# Did Korach and friends sin in the Golden Calf?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, mysticism-kabbalah, golden-calf-egel, parshat-korach

There is a tradition in קבלה that קרח was secretly righteous and will come back in the end times and rise up. (They are not clear exactly about what he will do).

I am wondering if part of what contributed to that view was potentially that (maybe?) He and his friends were not part of the Golden Calf.

Are there any sources on the matter?

Comment: Wouldn't he have been killed if he was? Besides, he was a Levi.

Comment: Moshe prayed for them not to be killed. I know he was a Levi but Im wondering if theres more פרשנות on the matter

Comment: Moshe prayed for who not to be killed?

Comment: He prayed for the people who sinned in the Golden Calf to not be killed

Comment: Not sure about that, but in any case they were: https://he.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94:%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%9C%D7%91_%D7%9B%D7%96

Comment: So youre saying everyone who sinned immediately died? Didnt almost the whole nation sin?

Comment: I am saying he prayed for that based on פרק כב דעת ותבונה who brings it from the אריזל

Comment: Korach was sinning during the golden calf, but his son was covering. He was jealous that Aaron's calf was selected to be the leader when he was more qualified.

Comment: @ClintEastwood where does it say that?

Comment: It wasn't "almost the entire nation," and in any case, as @shmosel is alluding to, not a single Levi sinned with the Golden Calf (Rashi, Devarim 32:9).

Comment: @zunior where's the kabbalistic source for your opening claim?

Comment: sorry. his sin was coveting

Comment: (מזולתו) הנה ס"ת צדיק' כתמר' יפרח', הוא קרח. לרמוז, אל שמואל הנביא, שהיה צדיק הבא מזרעו של קרח, כי כל תיקונו של קרח פריחתו ועלייתו מן גיהנם, היה ע"י שמואל בן בנו. וזש"ה בפרשת בלק, או מי יחיה משמו אל, ירצה, כי כבר ידעת, כי קיני הוא יתרו, שהוא גלגול קין, וגם הוא קרח, כמבואר אצלינו בפסוק כי שבעתים יק"ם קין, ר"ת 'יתרו 'קרח 'מצרי, ואמר, כי כשראה את הקני, אין לו תקומה וחיים להנצל ממיתה של גיהנם, כי אם ע"י שמואל, וז"ש מי יחיה משמו אל, משמואל כתיב:

https://www.sefaria.org/Sha'ar_HaPesukim,_Book_of_Psalms.143

Comment: @RabbiKaii Thats part of the source the rest I have in Sefarim from מהרצ"א not online. Let me know if thats enough

Comment: @RabbiKaii I was learning something else and I found it:

Comment: וזה שתראה בענין קרח בכל עושרו גם כן נאבד. וז"ש רז"ל שלקח מקח ר"ע, הוא היפך הטו"ב שהוא השלו"ם. וז"ש תורה ויקח קרח ולא פירש מה, להורות שלקח דבר שאינו מחזיק כלל, כי אינו כלי להחזיק. וז"ש  עד לעתיד במהרה בימינו שיבוא אליהו לעשות שלום בעולם (עדיות פ"ח מ"ז), אז צדי"ק כתמ"ר יפר"ח 

https://www.sefaria.org/Agra_DeKala,_Korach.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can extrapolate from [Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Exodus.32.20.2) on [Shemos 32:20](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.32.20):

> ויקח את־העגל אשר עשו וישרף באש ויטחן עד אשר־דק ויזר על־פני המים וישק את־בני ישראל
>
> He took the calf that they had made and burned it; he ground it to powder and strewed it upon the water and so made the Israelites drink it.

Rashi:

> וישק את בני ישראל. נתכון לבדקן כסוטות; שלש מיתות נדונו שם, אם יש עדים והתראה בסיף – כמשפט אנשי עיר הנדחת שהן מרבין – עדים בלא התראה במגפה, שנאמר ויגף ה' את העם, לא עדים ולא התראה בהדרוקן, שבדקום המים וצבו בטניהם (יומא ס"ו):
> וישק את בני ישראל
>
> AND HE GAVE THE CHILDREN OF ISRAEL TO DRINK OF IT — He intended to put them to the test as faithless wives were tried (cf. Numbers 5:12—31) (Avodah Zarah 44a). Three different death-penalties were inflicted there: It there were witnesses to the act of idolatry and a legal warning had preceded the deed the offender was put to death by the sword (cf. vv. 27, 28) as was the regulation regarding the inhabitants of an apostate city (Deuteronomy 13:13—18) when there were many (as was the case here; a single idolator, however, was subject to the death by stoning; cf. Deuteronomy 17:2—5). If there were witnesses but there had been no caution, they were destroyed by the plague, as it is said, (v. 35) “And the Lord plagued the people”. In cases where there were neither witnesses nor warning they were punished by dropsy — for the water which Moses gave them to drink put them to the test and if they were guilty their bellies swelled (cf. Yoma 66b).

In this Rashi, everyone who worshipped the Calf was accounted for and suffered death. As others have pointed out, the Levites gathered around Moshe to kill those who needed that type of death; regardless of that point, though, we can extrapolate from Korach's life itself that he didn't worship.